# Proving a conjugation map is an Inner automorphism of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Definition:
>
> The map
>
> $i_{g}:G\rightarrow G$
>
> $h\mapsto g^{-1}hg$

Lemma:

> $i_{g}$ is an Automorphism of G called an Inner Automorphism.

My attempt to prove this is as follows:

Let $x_{1},x_{2} \in G.$

Under the definition of the map $i_{g}$:

$\left ( x_{1} \ast x_{2} \right )i_{g}=g^{-1}\left ( x_{1} \ast x_{2} \right )g=g^{-1}x_{1}g \ast g^{-1}x_{2}g=\left ( x_{1} \right )i_{g} \ast \left ( x_{2} \right )i_{g}.$

And indeed, we have automorphism of G. Since this is an automorphism under the map defined by $i_{g}$, we have an Inner automorphism. Is this valid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't prove that it is an isomorphism, but only that it is a morphism. you also have to prove it is bijective (invertible)   (and most people would write $i_g(x)$ not $(x)i_g$)

Comment: @user1952009 Is morphism = homomorphism? I haven't heard of morphism.

Comment: yes if you want, note that $f(x) = e$ is a group (homo)morphism $G \to G$, and it is clearly not bijective